# Using branches for a mini project or module of project: Good practice?

Tags: mercurial, version-control

In my repo I have 3 closely related mini projects: 1 server and 2 clients. They are all quite small (<3 files each). Since they are so small and so closely related I just dropped them in folders in one single repo. However now that I know I can't clone a single directory in my VCS of choice (Mercurial), I'm considering splitting them up.

However I'm confused about general best practice: Is it okay to put different small projects in different branches, or should they all go in different repos?

I'm currently leaning towards branching since I can't easily splice out the file history of the different projects but then your using a feature in a way it wasn't meant to be used.

Comment: I'm 100% sure if this goes on SO or here. I choose here because its highly subjective and is general enough to apply to multiple VCS's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forme this really depends on how "connected" the mini projects are. If one changes do the others need to be changed as well to handle say a change to the database scheme?

If the answer is yes then I would keep them together in the repository, otherwise each could live in it's own repo.

Branching i don't believe is the right metaphor for your problem.

Comment: I don't really want to split them up into multiple repos due to how difficult it is to migrate the history of a file and the fact that the projects are really small. It just feels heavy to give each project its own dedicated repo. And to answer your question: Since this is a tightly integrated server-client project then yes, an update to the server most likely requires an update to the client.

Comment: No worries, then i'd go with keeping them in the same repo and allowing them to be branched/merged/tagged as one unit. This will help you in the future when you have a feature branch that covers more than one mini-project.